# scraping a table from website using pandas and saving to csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, export-to-csv

Iam new to python, I scraping a table from website using pandas and saving it as a csv file and running the code in a loop every 60 seconds.
I want the file name to be different or numbered every time the loop runs. I have tried the below

```
import pandas as pd
import time
starttime = time.time()
i=1
while True:
     url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/indexfutures/nifty/9/2021-05-27/OPTIDX/CE/12800.00/true
     optionchain = pd.read_html(url,attrs = {'class' : 'tblopt'})
     chaindata = pd.DataFrame(optionchain[1])
     chaindata1 = chaindata.rename(columns={0:'LTPcall',1:'Net Change',2:'Volume',3:'Open 
     Interest',4:'Change In Open Int',5:'StrikePrice',6:'LTPput',7:'Net Change',8:'Volume',9:'Open 
     Interest',10:'Change In Open Int'})
     s = 'file'
     x = (s+str(i))
     chaindata1.to_csv(r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\data\%x.csv')
     i=+1
     time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

by running this i get first file as file1 and then file(x) and it keeps overwritting file(x) i want it to flow file1,file2,file3 and so on

Comment: not sure why you are using a regex for filename instead of f-string .... you are not doing anything to substitute the file number into filename.  I'd recommend using path lib / Path instead of such not portable code for filenames

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scraper__, __scrape__, __scraped__) not scrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i=+1` doesn't do anything, it just assigns `+1` to `i`. Alson, you can use `str.format` to format the filename. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import time

starttime = time.time()
i = 1
while True:
    url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/indexfutures/nifty/9/2021-05-27/OPTIDX/CE/12800.00/true"
    optionchain = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"class": "tblopt"})
    chaindata = pd.DataFrame(optionchain[1])
    chaindata1 = chaindata.rename(
        columns={
            0: "LTPcall",
            1: "Net Change",
            2: "Volume",
            3: "Open Interest",
            4: "Change In Open Int",
            5: "StrikePrice",
            6: "LTPput",
            7: "Net Change",
            8: "Volume",
            9: "Open Interest",
            10: "Change In Open Int",
        }
    )
    chaindata1.to_csv(
        r"C:\Users\dell\Desktop\data\file{}.csv".format(i)
    )  # <-- use str.format here
    i += 1  # <-- use i += 1 instead of i = +1
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```